# Java conversion: dddd format to mm/dd

Tags: java, date

How do I go from dddd (1-365) and find the mm/dd of that year.
I can find the month, but struggle with finding the day of that month.

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the code you’ve written so far.  I will be particularly interested in whether you’re using the [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) class.

Comment: You need to know the year, or at least know whether it’s leap year to get conversions after February (or precisely after day 59 of the year) correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`LocalDate.ofYearDay(int year, int dayOfYear)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#ofYearDay-int-int-):

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.ofYearDay(2019, 107);

        System.out.println(date.getMonth()); // "APRIL"
        System.out.println(date.getDayOfMonth()); // "17"
    }
}
```